# Android maps v2 click on popup

Tags: android, google-maps

is there a way to launch an intent to another activity clicking in a google maps v2 popup?

This is my code:

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) 
{
    View popup=inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

    final TextView tvtitulo=(TextView)popup.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
    TextView tvDatos=(TextView)popup.findViewById(R.id.tvDatos);
    TextView tvCat=(TextView)popup.findViewById(R.id.tvCategoria);

    tvtitulo.setText(marker.getTitle());

    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(marker.getSnippet(), "?");
    final String first = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain "Fruit"
    String second = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain " they taste good"

    tvDatos.setText(first);
    tvCat.setText(second);

    ImageView imagen = (ImageView)popup.findViewById(R.id.menuImgView);

    if(marker.getTitle().substring(0,3).equalsIgnoreCase("Bar"))
        imagen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bar);

    else if(marker.getTitle().substring(0,3).equalsIgnoreCase("Res"))
        imagen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rest);
    else
        imagen.setVisibility(4);

    return(popup);
}
```

I would like to add something like this inside that method:

```
 popup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoLocal.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Thx for your answers and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, here take a look at how I did it,you have comments in the code to understand what is going on:

```
// Setting a custom info window adapter for the google map
        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker args) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker args) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                // Getting the position from the marker
                clickMarkerLatLng = args.getPosition();

                TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                title.setText(args.getTitle());

                map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {          
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
                    {
                        if (SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation!=null)
                        {   
                            if (String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) &&
                                    String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This your current location, navigation is not needed.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FlurryAgent.onEvent("Start navigation window was clicked from daily map");
                                tasksRepository = SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().tasksRepository.getTasksRepository();
                                for (Task tmptask : tasksRepository)
                                {
                                    String tempTaskLat = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude());
                                    String tempTaskLng = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLongtitude());

                                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8));

                                    if (tempTaskLat.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) && tempTaskLng.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                                    {  
                                        task = tmptask;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,RoadDirectionsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(TasksListActivity.KEY_ID, task.getId());
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your current location could not be found,\nNavigation is not possible.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
                return v;

            }
        });
```

Comment: i place a button on the popup dialog,and write the onclicklistener in the map.setInfoWindowAdapter() method for the button.but it is not working... what to do??? @EmilAdz

Comment: this won't work as the views you see in the infoWindow are not really your view but a bitmap that extracted from your defined layout.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but if you just want the click with the default View and not provide your own you just need this:

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
            {
            //do sth with  your  click

            }
        });
```