# PopupWindow not getting any TouchEvents

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, touch-event, android-popupwindow

I have a `MapFragment` in which, upon clicking a marker I'm showing a `PopupWindow`. I can't seem to get it to receive `TouchEvent`s though.

Here's what I've got atm:

```
mPopupWindow.getContentView().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Log.d("msg", "PopupWindow onClick");

    }

});
```

when invoking the particular PopupWindow:

```
mPopupWindow.setTouchable(true);
mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(mMapLinearLayout, x, y) //root is a subclass of LinearLayout
```

Haven't seen a message from the listener yet.

Edit: for your information: inside my window there are images that are loaded asynchronously

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876390/android-maps-v2-click-on-popup

Comment: I think I can't use the standard InfoWindow, since afaik it renders it as an image onto the map and in my window I have images that are being loaded asynchronously, meaning that only their placeholders would get rendered. 
On a side note: Should I load them on the UI thread instead maybe? They're downloaded, so it could become quite a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PopupWindow` has a pretty unintuitive bug concerning `TouchEvent`s. Found solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/DofKQS48a68).

Namely: `PopupWindow` **will not capture any events**, unless it has a background

```
mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable()); // you have to set background
mPopupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev)
    {
        Log.d("msg", "PopupWindow onTouch");
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```